How to shield drain pipe from impact from boxing bag?
I am installing a boxing bag. I will anchor it to the floor with bungies, but it is likely to hit a nearby drain pipe. How or what can I use to protect the drain pipe from impact? Some kind of covering perhaps? Relocation isn't an option due to space.

Welcome to DIY.SE! That suggestion in your comment is actually a decent answer. This site likes answers to be put in the Answer box, since comments can eventually get deleted.

I question the efficacy of simply protecting the pipe.  If the free range of motion for the bag is 18" (just to throw out a number) and the pipe+protection limits it to 12", you aren't going to get the same kind of movement out of the bag as it rebounds off the protection.

Can you provide more details about the orientation of the bag & drainpipe as well as how you are planning on anchoring to the floor with bungees?

Don't protect the pipe. (You haven't given us enough detail for answers anway.) Restrain the bag.
Install limiting chains or ropes that restrict movement in the direction of the pipe, anchored also to the floor or elsewhere. This will allow mostly free movement and won't require a bunch of hokey hardware doing the same job while taking up useful space.

To protect an object from impact, one can put something else in front of the object that can take the impact.
You could try building a floor-to-ceiling column of wood around the drain pipe. Leave a few inches / cm space between the pipe and the inside of the wood column. A column made of 3/4" (19mm) plywood, mounted firmly, would be suitably strong to stop a linebacker, let alone a boxing bag.
If the pipe is close to the wall such that a full four-side column can't be built, even better. Build a U-shape column and attach it to the ceiling, floor, and wall. Even stronger than the four-side column.
